# How do I fix a TypeError in a Google Sheets auto-sorter using the .sort command?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make an auto-sorter in google sheets but I get an error message when I try to run my code.  I searched for a solution online but could only find stuff related to JavaScript, and I'm not too sure how similar they are.  My code looks like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
["January", "February", "March"].forEach(function (s) {
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(s);
var range = sheet.getRange('L11:M40').getValues();
var result = range.filter(String);
result.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}])
```

And the error message I am getting is this:

```
TypeError: The comparison function must be either a function or undefined  
(anonymous)  @ Code.gs:35 <--(The result.sort line)  
onEdit  @ Code.gs:31 <--(The function onEdit line)
```

If I understand correctly, I need to nest the .sort command into another function, but I'm not sure how to do so. How would I go about doing so? I'm relatively new to programming so I'm not too sure what i am doing, especially with Google App Scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to sort your array data using [Range.sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj).

Since you already get the range values using [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and used [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), your result variable is an array. You can use [array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) which has an optional parameter `compareFunction` that defines an alternative sort order.

### Sample Sheet:

[image]

### Sample Code using Array.Sort():

```
function sortArray() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
  var range = sheet.getRange("L1:M5").getValues();
  var result = range.filter(String);
  Logger.log(result);
  result.sort(function(a,b){ return b[1]- a[1]
  });
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

### Output:

[image]

```
2:38:45 AM  Notice  Execution started
2:38:46 AM  Info    [[A, 1.0], [B, 2.0], [C, 3.0], [D, 4.0], [E, 5.0]]
2:38:46 AM  Info    [[E, 5.0], [D, 4.0], [C, 3.0], [B, 2.0], [A, 1.0]]
2:38:47 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

---

### Sample Code using Range.Sort():

```
function sortRange(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test");
  var range = sheet.getRange("L1:M5");
  Logger.log(range.getNumColumns());
  range.sort({column: 13, ascending: false});
  Logger.log(range.getValues());
}
```

### Output:

[image]

```
2:39:53 AM  Notice  Execution started
2:39:54 AM  Info    2.0
2:39:54 AM  Info    [[E, 5.0], [D, 4.0], [C, 3.0], [B, 2.0], [A, 1.0]]
2:39:55 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

- Notice that when using [Range.sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj), the sheet was updated/sorted automatically.
- Column number is not based on the range selected, rather it is based on the actual sheet column. Example if you want to sort column M, column value should be 13